# django model object and queryset save to other table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

using django 2.0.2 python3.4

skip details models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    postuid = models.BigAutoField(
        db_column='postUID', primary_key=True)
    useruid = models.Foreignkey .... skip
    content = models.Text       .... 
    registerdate = models.Date  ....

class KeepPost(models.Model):
    keeppostuid =  models.BigAutoField(
    db_column='KeepPostUID', primary_key=True)
    useruid = models.ForeignKey(
    'Userinfo', db_column='UserUID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    postuid =  models.ForeignKey(
    'Post', db_column='PostUID', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) 
    content = models.TextField(db_column='Content')
    registerdate = models.DateTimeField(
    db_column='RegisterDate')
    keepdate = models.DateTimeField(
    db_column='KeepDate')

class ReportPost(models.Model):
    reportuid=models.BigAutoField(
    db_column='ReportUID', primary_key=True)
    postuid=models.ForeignKey(
    'Post', db_column='PostUID', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) 
    #useruid is reporter
    useruid=models.ForeignKey(
    'Userinfo', db_column='UserUID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    registerdate = models.DateTimeField(
    db_column='RegisterDate'
```

`Post` to `KeepPost`

```
Post.objects.get(postuid=1) or Post.objects.filter(useruid=1)
KeepPost.objects.create(modelobjects or queryset)
```

`get()` is return model object , `filter()` is return queryset

if i want delete after reported

why use on_delete DO_NOTHING -> I want to keep a record even if ReportedPost is deleted

just one post deleted 
ex)

```
postmodel = Post.objects.get(postuid=request.get("postuid"))
```

want that models move to KeepPost and delete

```
postmodel.delete()
```

if user want delete account

```
usermodel = User.objects.get(useruid=useruid)
Postquery = usermodel.post_set.all()
reportPost = ReportPost.objects.filter(Q(postuid__in=Postquery))
```

i think move to KeepPost after intersect Postquery and reportPost

```
usermodel.delete()
```

Comment: @Shift 'N Tab
KeepPost is  store  Post at delete after report

Comment: It is still doesnt matter... you can still take advantage of the foreignkey, the fact that the KeepPost will store Post objects.

Comment: @Shift 'N Tab
if i changed postuid in KeePost to `ForeignKey("Post" ,db_column='PostUID', on_delete=models. DO_NOTHING)`

What's next??

Comment: remove all redundant fields and can you please post also your view? i can give you some hint how to achieve what you are trying to do

Comment: @Shift 'N Tab i added more information.. i don't have idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are what i might simply do.

**1. Remove `KeepPost` model.**

**2. Change Post model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField() 
    registerdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    archived_date = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def archive_post(self):
        if not self.is_archived:
            self.is_archived = True
            self.archived_date = datetime.now()
            self.save()
```

**Whats happening here??**

1. First you don't need a `KeepPost` model it is redundant since deleting and keeping a `Post` object will still maintain the data.
2. Removed `postuid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='postUID', primary_key=True)`. Django will automatically assign a primary key id.
3. Add `is_archived` and `archived_date` the simpliest way to keep an instance is not to delete it at all.

Now in your view you can simple use this, either you get your source from single instance or queryset.

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=1) # or id=1
post.archive_post
```

OR

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(user_id=1)

for post in posts:
    post.archive_post
```

If you want to delete a `Post` instance forever then call `.delete()` method.